# Переименование по значению в колонке большой таблице PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы, одна общая ('files') и одна (в рамках моего вопроса) зависимая ('concrete_files'), объединенные по внешнему ключу.
В главной таблице есть колонка с текстовым значением и мне нужно для всех элементов из зависимой таблицы поменять значение колонки в главной, если значение == "old_value".
Я это решил так простым скриптом:

```
UPDATE files as t1
SET value = 'new_value'
FROM concrete_files
WHERE t1.value = 'old_value'
```

По итогу миграция выполнялась очень долго (таблица размером 1Гб+, сколько там строк даже не знаю, бобру памяти не хватает открыть). Как можно исправить запрос, чтобы выполнялось быстрее? И возможно ли это?

Comment: А нафига в запросе вообще `concrete_files` - она в принципе не используется, условия связывания нету... может, следует добавить `.. AND t1.column=t2.column`?

Comment: Посчитать количество записей в таблице `select count(*) from concrete_files`. Если условие `t1.value = 'old_value'` срабатывает по большому количеству записей, то никак. Если условие срабатывает редко, то можно построить индекс по полю t1.value. Однако, если операция разовая, то просто выполнить и все.

Comment: @Akina а если в строке с FROM переписать на FROM files INNER JOIN concrete_files as t2 ON files.uuid  = t2.file?